# Why am I unable to call the method in my object - error: Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: javascript

I am reading up on JavaScript and I came up with this simple code snippet

```
var student = function(){
   this._name = "";
   this._funct = function(){
        console.log(this._name);
    }
}

student._name="alax";
console.log(student._name);
student._funct(); //Fails - error: Uncaught TypeError: student._funct is not a function
```

My last statement fails. Can anyone tell me why it is failing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't instantiated an instance of student. You could change it to:

```
var Student = function(){
   this._name = "";
   this._funct = function(){
        console.log(this._name);
    }
}

var student = new Student()
student._name="alax";
console.log(student._name); // alax
student._funct(); // alax
```

Read more about [prototype-inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: I know it works with using the keyword new but I was curious as to why it fails if I dont use the new keyword

Comment: take a look at the link i included. if you console.log the student object, you'll notice the _name doesn't exist either until you add it, then the student becomes an object with 2 properties (function object and _name).

Comment: from what i read is that prototype is used for inheritance. Why can I set the properties when new is used then ?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Can you explain why we can add properties to a function when the new keyword is used ?

Comment: Is it because "In other words, we tell JavaScript to execute a function and return an object. Any this bindings in the function are made on the object being returned."

Comment: Exactly, student is a constructor function and it's `this` context is returned when the constructor is called, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the new ES6 class keyword to create an instance. You can use getters and setters to get the name as well as call on the property. Here is a simple example of what your trying to do. However you create the object, you must create an instance of it using the new keyword to return that specific object with specific properties.

```
class Student{

    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
    }

    getName(){
        return this.name
    }

}

let mike = new Student('Mike');
console.log(mike.getName());
console.log(mike.name);
```